# Zend Framework 2 phpunit testing a table with a join

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-framework2

I have used Album example from Zend Framework 2 Documentation and created a application.

Now while unittesting it using `phpunit` I am having an issue while testing a table which is having a `join` with say table `Account_Type`.

Here is the code for it.

`fetchAll` function is

```
function fetachAll()
{
    $sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->getAdapter());

    $select = $sql->select();

    $select->from('Album')
           ->columns(array('id', 'name', 'account_type_id', 'managing_account_id'))
       ->join(array('AT' => 'account_type'), 'album.account_type_id = AT.account_type_id');

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

    return $resultSet; 
}
```

Unit test code for above table is.

```
public function testFetchAllReturnsAllAlbums()
{
    $resultSet= new ResultSet();

    $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock(
        'Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', 
        array('select'), 
        array(), 
        '', 
        false
    );    

    $mockTableGateway->expects($this->once())
                     ->method('select')
                     ->with()
                     ->will($this->returnValue($resultSet));

    $albumTable = new AlbumTable($mockTableGateway);

    $this->assertSame($resultSet, $albumTable->fetchAll());
}
```

I am getting error this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Zend\Db\Sql\Sql::__construct() must be an instance of
Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, null given,
```

for this line `$this->assertSame($resultSet, $albumTable->fetchAll());` in `testFetchAllReturnsAllAlbums` method.

If any one have done phpunit testing for join, please provide an example for the same.

Comment: You are calling `$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()` on your mock object, which returns NULL, and `Zend\Db\Sql\Sql` expects an instance of `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`. I am not very familiar with mock objects yet, but aren't you mocking the `select` method on the `TableGateway`, but in your `AlbumTable`, you are calling the `select` method on the `Sql` object?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to mock the `getAdapter` method of your `Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway` object. This method is called and its returned value passed to the `Zend\Db\Sql\Sql` constructor.